# How to compare two dates(MM/DD/YY) in 'Groovy Scripts' and display results in 'days' difference?

Tags: date, groovy

How to compare two dates(MM/DD/YY) in Groovy Scripts. Comparison logic should compare years, months, days and display the consolidated difference in 'Days'.  Below are possible dates scenarios for comparison. Please assist.

Date 1 -> 10/20/00
Date 2 -> 01/15/00

Date 1-> 1/1/20
Date 2-> 12/31/00

I have tried below

Option 1
use(groovy.time.TimeCategory)
def duration = (date-date2)

Outcome:
Runtime Error. Exception in thread "main" groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: days for class: java.lang.String

Option 2:
olddate.compareTo(newdate).

Outcome:
Difference in years, months is not calculating properly and so the difference days is not correct.

Comment: You have to parse the date.  Then subtracting them from each other gives you the distance in days.

Answer (score 1):

```
Date.parse('MM/dd/yy', '10/20/00') - Date.parse('MM/dd/yy', '01/15/00')
```